# Интеграл от таблично заданной функции двух переменных в C

Tags: c, математика, численные-методы

Нужно найти повторный интеграл функции двух переменных f(x,y). Аналитическое выражения для функции не известно, известна только табличка ее значений на фиксированной сетке. Подскажите пожалуйста наиболее оптимальный для этого способ, и в какой библиотеке его можно найти.
Мне приходит в голову только искать поточечно подынтегральное выражение как функцию x (интегрируя по y методом Симпсона), а потом тем же Симпсоном интегрировать полученный массив по x. Но наверняка есть более оптимальные алгоритмы...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если все что известно о функции - это набор точек, то проще всего методом трапеций посчитать.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо! Но может есть более точные методы?..

Comment: Если сетка равномерная, то любым из регулярных способов, тот же метод Симпсона отлично сработает. Если сетка неравномерная - можно или поискать, или просто вывести (это несложно) формулы для такого варианта. Трапеции - это все же первое приближение, Симпсон будет точнее...

Comment: @Lista нельзя определить более точен метод или нет, если вся информация о функции - это координаты точек. Если известно, что функция более-менее гладкая, то можно аппроксимировать функцию полиномом (в простейшем случае - параболами, как в методе Симпсона). Если функция на самом деле ведет себя "хаотично" (например, куча волн между точками), то любой метод даст точность примерно "пальцем в небо".

Comment: Т.е., я хочу сказать, что если нет какой-то метрики, с помощью которой можно было бы определить, насколько точен полученный результат, то нет особого смысла и пытаться сделать точнее, чем метод трапеций (или метод Симпсона).

Comment: @insolor, спасибо большое. Функция по физ смыслу должна быть гладкая, буду пробовать считать методом Симпсона.